# Can not load kml files which was in my local server?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, kml

Tried to load the below KML file in my application. I can access the file from the browser itself. But the file is not rendered in the google maps. Tried to check the KML Layer status, getting a weird result as **"undefined"**. I dont know what i am missing. Please help me to study about KML Layer with Google Maps.

**INTERESTING FACT :**
   Kml Layer has been rendered in the google maps, If I have used google's KML url http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ggeoxml/cta.kml . I dont know Why the google map is rendering the KML layer from the google server. And Why it is not rendering KML layer from my server (http://www.mylocalIPAddress.com/WebModule/polygon.kml). But I am sure nothing is blocking my KML file. If i have hit the URL at the browser. I can view the file. So nothing is blocking the file. But Dont know Why I cant load my kml file .

**KML File :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <ScreenOverlay>
    <name>Absolute Positioning: Top left</name>
    <Icon>
      <href>http://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/images/top_left.jpg</href>
    </Icon>
    <overlayXY x="0" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <screenXY x="0" y="1" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <rotationXY x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
    <size x="0" y="0" xunits="fraction" yunits="fraction"/>
  </ScreenOverlay>
</kml>
```

**JavaScript :**

```
google.maps.visualRefresh = true;
var map;
function initialize() {
    // Specifies the google Map properties
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
        zoom : 3,
        center : new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
        mapTypeId : google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
    var layer   =   new google.maps.KmlLayer('http://www.mylocalIPAddress.com/WebModule/polygon.kml');
    layer.setMap(map);
    console.log(layer.getStatus());
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

** SPECIAL HINT :**
When checking the response of the google link , I have got the following

```
 _xdc_._nox6ih && _xdc_._nox6ih( [0,"kml:cOyYrFGigX5u4USCpzso8ggEWKR7NP4TNfjRaORI","|ks:;dc:tb;ts:46343661|kv:3|api:3",["Chicago Transit Map","Chicago Transit Authority train lines","Chicago Transit Authority train lines"],[[41.721877,-87.8929],[42.072787,-87.606048]],[["gfd29185067c55f5f"],["g5e295bda04f08836"],["ga24949030bee7e8c"],["g55e98e4a4c0ba15f"],["g51d583df1e7a5451"],["g72b37441838ae58e"],["g4da782bd5142613c"],["ge63204f1f8e4087a"]],1,[["client","2"]],42,[["ks",";dc:tb;ts:46343661"],["kv","3"],["api","3"]]] )
```

And Again when i have checked the response of my server, I have got the following

```
_xdc_._ghavva && _xdc_._ghavva( [0,null,null,null,null,null,4,[["client","2"]]] )
```

I dont know why am i getting null as a response. I believe due to the null response, google maps can not render the KML file.

Comment: *So nothing is blocking the file*

How can you be sure?

**The file must be public available for everyone.**

When you  are able to load this file from your computer, it doesn't  mean that everybody may access this file.

Check your firewall-settings, usually a firewall should block such requests(but may allow them from your own network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by parsing [geoxml3.js](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml-v3/) library.

Changed the kml file as a xml file. and parsed the xml file with the geoxml3 library. Now I can load the KML files in my application.

The script I have parsed is below.

```
var geoXml = new geoXML3.parser({
     map: map,
     singleInfoWindow: true
     });
geoXml.parse('polygon.xml');
```

**HINT**
I dont know whether it is a work around or not. But it solved my problem. Please guide me whether i am doing correct by your valuable comments.

Answer (score 3):

Have you added the mime-type for KML on your server?

Try adding to your .htaccess file:

```
AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml    kml
AddType application/vnd.google-earth.kmz        kmz
```

Comment: I am using JBoss as my server. Could you please share me the filename of .htaccess in JBoss Server.

Comment: Ah sorry, I've only ever used Apache server. This page has a possible solution for you in the 3rd post, however it is from 2009 and could be outdated. Good luck!
https://community.jboss.org/thread/65562?start=0&tstart=0&_sscc=t

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am working with your way. I will post the result once if i have solved the issue.

Comment: When hosting in IIS, you must manually add these MIME types in order for local KMZ files to work.